# clojure: How do I use while/loop with sleep

Tags: clojure

I want to call a function every second.

I have the following code:

```
(defn dostuff []
  (do
    (print "I'm doing stuff")
    ...))

(while true
  (Thread/sleep 1000)
  (dostuff))
```

I would expect this to print "I'm doing stuff" every second but it does not.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are calling print instead of println. It doesn't auto-flush.

Answer (score 4):

You're not flushing stdout. You can either use println, which is `print` plus `newline` (forces auto-flush), or explicitly call flush like this:

```
(defn dostuff []
  (do
    ...
    (print "I'm doing stuff")
    (flush)))
```